# Creating a transparent window within Unity window

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm planning to write an editor window. When I open this editor window, I want it to start from the last mouse position and have a transparent background. How can I achieve this?

Based on my research, I've come to understand that if I use EditörWindow, making the background transparent is impossible. Is there any other alternative? Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: On Windows an editor window is a HWND, so you can first [get the handle](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-you-reliably-the-hwnd-window-handle-of-the-games-own-window.528444/), and then use the [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) function to change its opacity.

Comment: Will it work for the EditorWindow I've written myself?